# Finding number of strings of length $n$ composed of $x, y, z$ such that the maximal string of $x$ or $y$ is of even-order length

Tags: combinatorics

**Exercise.** Find the number of ways of creating a string consisting of $x,y$ and $z$ of length $n$ so that the **maximal** string of $x$ or $y$ is of an even-order length.

I tried to create a recursive sequence, but I got stuck. I stated that there are three ways to start the string:

- $z$ is the first element: Then, let $f(n)$ be the function of the number of legal strings – There $f(n-1)$ legal permutations remaining.
- If either $x$ or $y$ is the opening term, then I obtain two problems: First, if I say that the second element is $z$, I have to make sure that there exists a string of $x$ or $y$ of length $2$, at least, since the **maximal** series of $x$ or $y$ must be of an even-order length. If the second term is either $x$ or $y$, I receive restrictions for the third term.

I do not know how to continue from here.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Let $f(n,m)$ is count of $n$-strings having maximal $xy$-substring of length $m$. Let string begins with $xy$-substring of length $k$, then $f(n,m)=\sum_{k=0}^m f(n-1-k,m)$. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ $f(n,m)=0$ for $n<m$ and $f(n,n)=2^n$.

Comment: When you say maximal substring of $x$ or $y$: Does that mean strings of $x$s and $y$s (possibly mixed); or does it mean pure $x$ or pure $y$. For instance does $xxyzx$ have a maximal substring of interest being length $2$ ($xx$) or length $3$ ($xxy$)?

Comment: x's and y's can be mixed, and the substring they form may the maximal.

Comment: I counted for small $n$ and obtained 1,5,9,45,113,389,1081..., which was not registered in https://oeis.org/. Using only $x$ and $z$, I got 1,2,3,7,14,30,62... which was equivalent to https://oeis.org/A103421. I imagine that the general term may be difficult to describe.

Comment: @aerile Ok. Thank you.